# Is pointwise multiplication by a smooth non zero function a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Say $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is nowhere zero (like e.g. the constant map 1). Is the map $x \mapsto x f(x)$ a diffeomorphism?

It seems to me that the answer is no because the derivative of a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R$ is non zero everywhere.

But on the other hand I don't understand why for example $x \mapsto 2 x$ is not a diffeomorphism!

> Please could someone resolve my confusion?

Comment: $x \mapsto 2x$ is a diffeomorphism; there's no problem there. If $x \mapsto xf(x)$ is a diffeomorphism, then $(xf)' = xf'(x)+f(x)$ is nonzero for all $x$, so that rules out some functions $f$. For instance, $f$ cannot be $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Why did you not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $f(x)=\frac1x$.

To address the last point, $x \mapsto 2 x$ **is** a diffeomorphism.

Comment: The question requires a function $f$ defined over all of $\mathbb{R}$ and obviously $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not defined at $x = 0$. You need to fix that.

Comment: Fine, let $f(0)=42$.

Comment: Even though I agree with the spirit of Chris's comment, I guess it should be pointed out that the above $f$ can be made smooth on all $\mathbb{R}$. It only needs to coincide with $x\mapsto1/x$ on some interval.